# A hotkey in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am writing `\sum_{min}^{max}`.
How to jump after writing 'min' to 'max' by hotkey? I thought key <kbd>Tab</kbd> works like in other software, but it doesn't.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Right arrow key`. Otherwise you can configure it to whatever you want in the shortcut settings under `Editor->Basic key mapping->Next placeholder`.

Answer (score 6):

In TeXstudio, the keyboard shortcut to jump placeholder is not the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>. If you would like to change it to <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can do so if you go to

> Configure TeXstudio -> Shortcuts -> Editor -> Basic Key Mapping -> Next Placeholder.

[image: TeXstudio settings]